# Laravel builder - specify a connection on the builder object

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an eloquent query builder in Laravel

`$builder = Model::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');`

I want to specify a connection to use, because I have a separate db for some data - let's call it 'archive' for example.

Now, I know I can do it statically, like `$builder = Model::connection('archive');` [edit] `::on('archive');` apparently

But if I already have the `$builder` object, and can't use the static function, how can I do it on the builder object?

I've tried

```
$builder->connection('archive');
$builder->onConnection('archive');
$builder->setConnection('archive');
```

And these are all failing for me.

Comment: I thought it was `on` but can't find it in the documentation. The code would then be `$builder->on('archive');`

Comment: hmm, didn't seem to work for me

Comment: Model::on works though, @DouwedeHaan

Comment: I've been looking around in the code a bit but it seems that the connection can only be set on the initialisation of the model. Hope it still helps though!

Comment: After searching a bit, [maybe this could help](https://sasablagojevic.com/changing-the-database-connection-on-laravel%27s-query-builder)

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions.

1. Define in class

```
class MyModel extends Model {

    protected $connection= 'archive';

    protected $table = 'table_name';
}
```

2. In a query

```
(new MyModel())->on('archive')->get();
```